# Sequelize.js: One to Many relationship eager load with custom field

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am writting an app with node, express, sequelize and I have a little problem. I am trying to eager load a model on the "one part" of the relationship.

I get this SQL:

```
Executing: SELECT `albaran`.*, `cliente`.`ClienteID` AS `cliente.ClienteID`, 
`cliente`.`NombreES` AS `cliente.NombreES` FROM `albaran` LEFT OUTER JOIN `cliente` AS 
`cliente` ON `albaran`.`AlbaranNo` = `cliente`.`ClienteID` WHERE 
`albaran`.`AlbaranNo`='2013100001';
```

and I need it to be:

```
Executing: SELECT `albaran`.*, `cliente`.`ClienteID` AS `cliente.ClienteID`, 
`cliente`.`NombreES` AS `cliente.NombreES` FROM `albaran` LEFT OUTER JOIN `cliente` AS 
`cliente` ON `albaran`.`ClienteID` = `cliente`.`ClienteID` WHERE 
`albaran`.`AlbaranNo`='2013100001';
```

So I could access it at the view (now I get an empty string):

```
#{albaran.cliente.NombreES}
```

This is the code:

albaran.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define("Albaran", {
        AlbaranNo: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT,  primaryKey: true},
        ClienteID: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING, //this must be string, I am not who defined the db
            references: "Cliente",
            referencesKey: "ClienteID"
        }},{
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true,
            tableName: 'albaran'
        })
     }
```

cliente.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define("Cliente", {
        ClienteID: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true
        },
        NombreES: DataTypes.STRING
    },{
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'cliente'
    })
}
```

associations

```
db.Albaran.hasOne(db.Cliente, {as: "cliente", foreignKey: 'ClienteID'});
```

router

```
exports.albaran = function(req, res) {
    db.Albaran.findAll({ include: [{ model: db.Cliente, as: "cliente" }]})
    .success(function (albaranes){
        res.render("albaranes", {albaranes: albaranes});
    });
};
```

Thank you very much. I hope I explained myself clearly.

Edition:

I found the solution modifying the association:

```
db.Albaran.belongsTo(db.Cliente, {as: "cliente", foreignKey: 'ClienteID', primaryKey: 'ClienteID'});
db.Cliente.hasMany(db.Albaran, {as: "albaranes", foreignKey: 'ClienteID'});
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: When you describe the relationship between your `Albaran` model and your `Cliente` model you're saying that `Albaran` is linked to `Cliente` via the field `cliente.ClienteID` which stored `albaran.AlbaranNo`. In other words, sequelize is expecting you to have a field containing a foreign `AlbaranNo` on `Cliente` due to the way it makes associations. You could try associating them in reverse (i.e. `db.Cliente.hasOne(db.Albaran, {as: "albaran", foreignKey: "ClienteID"})` which may work for. As for customizing that relationship like you've already described it, I don't know if that will work.

Comment: Excuse me, I had in mind One to One relationship so I wrote wrongly the question title. It's One to Many, one **cliente** to many **albaran**. So, I can't put AlbaranNo on Cliente and I can't write the association you suggested. P.D:Really sorry, I am new at SO. How can I correct the tittle?

Answer (score 2):

This may be it:

```
db.Cliente.hasMany(db.Albaran, {as: "albaran", foreignKey: 'ClienteID'});
```

More info here: http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#associations-one-to-many

The other side is:

db.Albaran.hasOne(db.Cliente, {as: "cliente", foreignKey: 'AlbaranNo"});

Comment: I did this one, so I can get correctly `db.Cliente.find({ where: { ClienteID: clienteID },include: [{ model: db.Albaran, as: "albaranes" }]}) .success(function (cliente){ res.render('clienteDetalle', {cliente: cliente}); }); }` but I want the inverse operation: `db.Albaran.findAll({ include: [{ model: db.Cliente, as: "cliente" }]}) .success(function (albaranes){ res.render("albaranes", {albaranes: albaranes}); });` I think the documentation that could help me is missing in the link you gave me, just after this piece of text: ...just leave it the way it is and let it be a one-way association...